# Angular- How to prevent text in input from showing if input is invalid

Tags: angular, validation, input

I have an input text tag with [(ngModel)]=some_var . When the user inputs something that isn't a number or decimal, I want it to not show in the input box when typing. For example, if I type h in the text box I don't want to see h as I type it (if that makes sense).

I'm not sure which event to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want numbers and dot as a decimal separator, you can just use:

```
<input type="number" (...) >
```

Comment: What if I wanted to allow +/- too?

Comment: Type 'number' allows + and - too.